# How to use buttons as spinners on input elements with same style but different I.Ds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project which consists of users and i am querying an SQL database to echo all users now i have styled everything and there's an input element beside each user which starts at a value of zero and there are two button one to make the value of the input element to increase(#up) and decrease(#down) respectively.So the two buttons are acting as spinners and i also want to set a  minimum value of 5 and maximum value of 500 for the input element.

I have tried many 'onclick' functions all to no avail ... I tried using 'GetElementById' but this only changes the value of the input element of the first user and I know it is because of the I.D.so What can i do to change this

Please all help is appreciated. I'm a beginner so if i made a mistake please correct me instead of downvoting.
Thanks.

Here is the HTML :

```
               <span class = 'username'>".$row['username']."</span>
               <form name = 'matchcreator' id='amount' action='arena.php' method ='post'>
               <input  name = 'm-maker' type = 'text' id='price'  maxlength = '15' value='0'/>
               <button id='up' type ='button' ><img src='images/up.png'  width='10px' height='10px' href='#'> </button>
               <button id='down' type ='button' '><img src='images/down.png' width='10px' height='10px' href='#'></button>
                </form>
```

Comment: The problem is that you're having multiple DOM elements with the same ID, you should use classes in this case

Comment: thank you vn you please show me an example @AlonEitan

Comment: I added a simple and basic example of how to implement it using classes

Answer (score 1):

You can either do as David Cash suggested and take advantage of the HTML5 input element with built-in spinners, or you can remove the IDs off of the up/down arrows as well as the input element itself. It would look something like as follows:

## HTML

```
    <span class = 'username'>".$row['username']."</span>
    <form name = 'matchcreator' id='amount' action='arena.php' method ='post'>
        <input  name = 'm-maker' type = 'text' class='price'  maxlength = '15' value='0'/>
        <button class='up' type ='button'><img src='images/up.png'  width='10px' height='10px' href='#'> </button>
        <button class='down' type ='button'><img src='images/down.png' width='10px' height='10px' href='#'></button>
    </form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
    $(".up").on("click", function () {
        var trigger = $(this);
        var input = trigger.prev();
        if (Number(input.val()) < 500) {
            input.val(Number(input.val()) + 1);
        }
        else { alert("max value reached"); }
    }); 
    $(".down").on("click", function () {
        var trigger = $(this);
        var input = trigger.prev().prev();
        if (Number(input.val()) > 5) {
            input.val(Number(input.val()) - 1);
        }
        else { alert("min value reached"); }
    });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Based on your comment to @Alon Eitan, we may need to give you the full context of the code. I'll edit my answer now.

Comment: @sean Try pasting that code into the <body> of your html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using just simple HTML 5 for your input box?

```
<input name ="m-maker" name="price" type="number" min="1" max="500" value="5">
```

That should be enough to create the input box with spinners.  You shouldn't need buttons to increase or decrease the value in the input box.

Here's a example on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/owL12i2x4OthysDCcrwc?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

As requested in the comment, here is an example of what you're trying, but using classes instead of ID

```
<form name = 'matchcreator' class='amount' action='arena.php' method ='post'>
           <input  name = 'm-maker' type = 'text' class='price'  maxlength = '15' value='0'/>
           <button class='up' type ='button' ><img src='images/up.png'  width='10px' height='10px' href='#'> </button>
           <button class='down' type ='button' '><img src='images/down.png' width='10px' height='10px' href='#'></button>
 </form>
```

Example of jQuery:

```
$(".down").on("click", function() {
    var input = $(this).prev(".price");
    input.val( parseInt(input.val())-- );
});

$(".up").on("click", function() {
    var input = $(this).prev(".price");
    input.val( parseInt(input.val())++ );
});
```

Comment: i'm very grateful but its still not working do you put it in the same page as the html or in a diffrent page.

Comment: You need to wrap it inside `$(document).ready()` event, this is just a simple snippet of the general approach of using classes with jquery